# Set redirection from inside function in bash

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I’d like to do something of this form:

```
one() {
  redirect_stderr_to '/tmp/file_one'

  # function commands
}

two() {
  redirect_stderr_to '/tmp/file_two'

  # function commands
}

one
two
```

This would run `one` and `two` in succession, redirecting `stderr` to the respective files. The working equivalent would be:

```
one() {
  # function commands
}

two() {
  # function commands
}

one 2> '/tmp/file_one'
two 2> '/tmp/file_two'
```

But that is a bit ugly. I’d rather just have all the redirection instructions inside the functions themselves. It’d be easier to manage. I have a feeling this might not be possible, but want to be sure.

Comment: just in case you need a test command `echo test 1>&2` will write to stderr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest and most robust approach is to use ***function-level* redirection**: note how a **redirection command is applied to *whole functions*, after the closing `}`** below and is **scoped to each function** (no need to reset):

```
# Define functions with redirected stderr streams.
one() {
  # Write something to stderr:
  echo one >&2
} 2> '/tmp/file_one'

two() {
  # Write something to stderr:
  echo two >&2
} 2> '/tmp/file_two'

one
two

# Since the function-level redirections are localized to each function,
# this will again print to the terminal.
echo "done" >&2
```

**Documentation links** (thanks, [@gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf)):

- [*Shell Functions* in the Bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Functions)
- [*Function Definition Command* in the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_05)

  - Note that this implies that the feature is POSIX-compliant, and you can use it in `sh` (POSIX-features-only) scripts, too.

Comment: This is definitely the best answer. For references: [_Shell Functions_ in the Bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Functions), and [_Function Definition Command_ in the POSIX specs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_05).

Comment: Thanks, @gniourf_gniourf; didn't know that the feature is POSIX-compliant, too. I've added your links to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`exec`](http://ss64.com/bash/exec.html) builtin (notice the effect of `exec` is not canceled once the function returns):

```
one() {
  exec 2> '/tmp/file_one'

  # function commands
}

two() {
  exec 2> '/tmp/file_two'

  # function commands
}

one # stderr redirected to /tmp/file_one
echo "hello world" >&2 # this is also redirected to /tmp/file_one
exec 2> "$(tty)" # here you are setting the default again (your terminal)
echo "hello world" >&2 # this is wrtitten in your terminal
two # stderr redirected to /tmp/file_two
```

---

Now, if you want to apply the redirection only to the function, the best approach is in [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33193350/4095830).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use :

```
#!/bin/bash

    one() {
      (
      # function commands
      ) 2> /tmp/file_one
    }

    two() {
      (
      # function commands
      ) 2> /tmp/file_two
    }

    one
    two
```

Comment: That works, and localizes the redirection to the interior of each function, which is good, but using a _subshell_ `(...)` has side-effects, both in terms of being able to affect the current shell's environment and, probably less importantly so, performance. You can actually apply redirections to _functions as a whole_, without the need for a subshell.